# Magento Tax percentage upload

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, tax-class

Currently in magento we upload the tax percentage information using a tax class id. However, we note that the tax class ids are changing between local, staging and live servers. As a result, we are not able to upload the product information(containing the tax information along with other product information) using the same csv.

In this regard, I have two questions

1. Why do the tax class ids change between local, staging and live servers for the same category ? This creates a problem  using the same csv for upload between different installations
2. Can we upload the tax percentage (say 10%) directly using the csv instead of giving a tax class id and then assigning a tax %age to that tax class id in two steps ?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, any suggestions on this please.

Comment: Did you get your solution?